# Is it always possible to arrange $n$ nodes in dimenson $n-1$ with equidistance between each other?

Tags: geometry

I want to construct a graph with $n$ nodes and with equal distance between each node. I was wondering if this is always possible in dimension $n-1$.
Take for instance a graph with three nodes. We can arrange them in the $\mathbb R^2$ as an equilateral triangle. Four nodes can be arranged as a tetrahedron in the $\mathbb R^3$ and so forth.

- Is this relationship always true?

Comment: Hint: Start with the orthonormal basis vectors $e_1,...,e_n$ in $R^n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So basically each node is located at $e_i$, $i = 1,...,n$ such that the distance between each node is given by $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @clueless That certainly seems to do the job! From there, it should be noted that any $n$ points lie in a common $(n-1)$-dimensional plane.

Comment: So yes: the relationship is always true.